# 16.04 static IP

Tags: 16.04

How do I temporarily change the IPv4 address of my wired interface?
I'm new to Linux from a Mac/Windows background. I need to set a static IP on my Ubuntu laptop. I tried to follow the instructions to edit the /etc/network/interfaces file but when I see the default file it doesn't look like what I expect. The instructions I have indicate that the default 'interfaces' file content should be: `auto enp0s3` but in my case what I see is

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: You can also set up your router to give the IP you want to the mac address  of your interface.

Comment: You found a cli solution without using Network Manager. That is not a recommended way for desktop computers,

Answer (score 3):

Click the Network Manager icon on you screen and select "Modify Connections".

Then modify your Ethernet connection. In the IPV4 tab switch to "manual" and type in the IP address, gateway, mask, etc.

After you set up the address, then disable and enable the connection to reset it with the new address.

Comment: Thanks, Pilot6. This is what I did initially before the CLi solution but instead of changing my IP address it bound a new address to the interface. So when I got to the 'network manager' and select 'connection information' I see the address I added under 'more addresses', but the DHCP address is still there as the primary address.

Comment: It looks like you type the address to a wrong place. And DHCP address should not change. And do not add "more addresses" but replace the existing one.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. When I select 'manual' from the interface drop down I don't see an address to edit. Only a place to add an address

Comment: So add an address, netmask and gateway. That's all you need. Then disable the wired network and enable it again.

Comment: That was it. Had to disable the wired network and enable it again. Thanks.